# how to use express and socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, express, socket.io

I am using express V 3.4.8 and socket.io V 0.9.16 to create a simple app wich render a map with markers placed where people is connecting to the site, all this in order to learn node.js and to use maps. My problem is that I can not get socket.io to work because is never delivered, more ahdead:

This is my server javascript:

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);


app.configure(function(){
    app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(app.router);
});

app.configure('development', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
});


io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.emit('news', {hello: 'world'});
    socket.on('my other event', function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });
});

server.listen(3000, 'localhost');


// console.log('Listening on port %d', server.address().port);
```

The logs im getting from my console are:

```
info: socket.io started
info: unhandled socket.io url
```

And this is my google's chrome log:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: io is not defined (index):21
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/plain:"http://localhost:3000/socket.io.js". (index):36
io is not defined
```

So I think the problem is the way express manage to deliver the files but as I am learning I dont understand really well what is happening backdooors. I wich someone could help me understanding why socket.io.js is not being delivered and how can i solve the problem. i appreciate your help guys!.

** Edit **
Also my file structure inside the project is somethins like:

```
mapApp
 -node_modules
 -public
   -css
   -img
   -js
   index.html
 app.js (which is the server)
```

This is also my client side js:

```
$(function(){

    // create a map in the "map" div, set the view to a given place and zoom
    var map = L.map('map',{
        center:[0,0],
        zoom:2,
        minzoom:2,
        maxZoom:18
    });

    // add an OpenStreetMap tile layer
    L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
    }).addTo(map);

    /* find user */
    map.locate({setView:true, maxZoom:16});

});

/* client socket*/
/* socket */
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');
    socket.on('news', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
});
```

my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <title>mapApp</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/leaflet.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/basic.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">

        <script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <h1>The map</h1>
        <div id="map"></div>

        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"><\/script>')</script>

        <script src="/socket.io.js"></script>
        <script src="js/vendor/leaflet.js"></script>
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a route handler to your server side code:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
   res.sendFile('index.html');
});
```

`index.html` will have your client side socket code. It has to import the clent side socket.io library.

```
<script src='/socket.io/socket.io.js' />
<script>
    var socket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:3000');
    socket.on('news', function (data) {
        console.log(data.msg);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: this is handling to deliver my static html as index.html app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));. Which  leads me to think that there is only delivering files inside public?...so how could i deliver socket.io?

Comment: @JhonnatanGonzalezRodriguez Could you post your client side code to the question as well?

Comment: @AmalAntony the method name is res.sendfile() not res.sendFile()